# Is there any open source software or gratis for cacti calculating bandwidth usage?

Tags: gratis, open-source, bandwidth

Is there any open source software or gratis for cacti calculating bandwidth usage?

In my case, I have WHMCS system, I want to calculate the server's bandwidth usage from it invoice start date to now.

Comment: Are you ***sure*** that you need [tag:open-source], and not just [tag:gratis]?  You are narrowing the field